# Make scrollbar track thicker than scrollbar thumb

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw many threads showing a thinner track than the scrollbar thumb but I want to make it in the complete opposite.

Scrollbar track thicker than the scrollbar thumb - is that possible ?

Comment: I assume the downvotes are due to you not showing what you've tried (if you have). You're asking a vague "is that possible" which is almost always a "yes", but you wouldn't be satisfied with a simple "yes". If you ask a more specific question "How do I create a scrollbar with a thicker track than thumb?" as well as show your attempts, it would be a much more complete question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Chrome (no Firefox) You can set right/left border on the scrollbar thumb to the same color as the scrollbar itself:

```css
.content
{
  --scrollbar-size: 30px;
  --scrollbar-color: #f8bbd0;
  --scrollbar-thumb-size: 15px;
  --scrollbar-thumb-color: #e91e63;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.overflow
{
  min-height: 450px;
}

.content::-webkit-scrollbar
{
  width: var(--scrollbar-size);
  background-color: var(--scrollbar-color)  ;
}

.content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
  border: calc((var(--scrollbar-size) - var(--scrollbar-thumb-size)) / 2) solid var(--scrollbar-color);
  background-color: var(--scrollbar-thumb-color);
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="overflow">
    some text
  </div>
  <div>end</div>
</div>
```

One limitation with this method: is not possible to make thumb with *nice* round corners.

Another solution would be creating your own custom scrollbar (there are plenty tutorials for that)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I solved my issue with outlining my scrollbar track, your solution is also nice.

Comment: You could also post your own answer, so others can benefit too ;)

Answer (score 1):

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #777
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555
}

.scroll {
    height: 15rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 20rem;
    direction: rtl;
    /* or */
    direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
 
 <div class='scroll'>
 <p>test</p> 
 <p>test</p>
 <p>test</p>
 <p>test</p>
 <p>test</p>
 <p>test</p>
 <p>test</p>
 <p>test</p>
 <p>test</p>
 <p>test</p>

 </div>
```

Comment: that's what I understood

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question was not "how to make scroolbar thinner"